# How do you target angular elements such as links without the href attribute?

Tags: ruby, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I'm having trouble targeting specific links on mobile layout. Here's the relevant code in my step definition:

```
within("div.mobile-header.home-header") do
  find("a.dropdown-top.ng-binding.ng-scope").click
  sleep 3
end
find("a", :text => 'Log out').click
```

Here's what it looks like on the page:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJtjT.png

In this mobile header dropdown, the bottom 2 links change dynamically based on whether you're logged in or not. When you're not logged in, those 2 links are "Register" and "Log In". When you're logged in, they're "Profile" and "Log out". When I try to click on 'Profile' or 'Log out', I get a 'Capybara::ElementNotFound' error, even though it's the same exact code I used to click on the other elements in that dropdown such as Home, Trip Planner, and Resources.

And here is the relevant code that for the element I'm trying to click.

```
<li data-ng-class="{'active': curPageTitle == 'Log out'}" data-ng-show="logged_in" class="">
<a data-ng-click="showDropdown = false; logout();">Log out</a></li>
```

Comment: Clicking the link works with the code provided. It might help to put a working example that would allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hm it's not working for me. When I run that, I get a "Capybara::ElementNotFound" error